# How to have vertical layout of navbar in mobile screen without collapse expand feature

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Edit: JS Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Q4atQ/
Edit: I am able to now get a vertical menu bar on a mobile screen that is not collapsible.
Now only thing left to figure out is how to make the vertical nav bar occupy the entire mobile screen.

I am building a simple HTML5 app which has a nav bar which should be displayed as such horizontally at the top of the page in a desktop browser with corresponding content below it.

I however want the nav bar to be displayed vertically on a mobile browser page and occupy the full screen without the expand collapse features or the triple line (hamburger) menu item.

I am using the following code as a starting point -

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse in">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
```

I am able to get an expanded nav bar but it does not occupy the full screen and the collapse option is still there.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the JS and CSS code as well.. So I can check for solution.. It is better to give jsfiddle of you working copy..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4atQ/ Here is the jsfiddle link ,how can I get eh nav menu to occupy full screen?

Answer (score 0):

Just using css, one way is :

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Q4atQ/1/

**Css**:

```
html, body, .container-full, .navbar{    
   height:100%;
}

.navbar{
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work :

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

.navbar {
  height:100vh;
  margin:0px;
 }
.navbar-nav{
  margin:0px;
 }

}
```